# Service for unpacking custom protected exes?

Tags: unpacking

Is there any free/paid service on internet to unpack custom protected exes? I am a RE but unpacking is not my expertise.

Thanks

Comment: It´s a 64bit binary for windows with a custom packer (exeinfo shows unknown protecttion). I have tried x64dbg but it seems the exe detects the debugger even with ScyllaHide and closes it. The exe detects memory BP and shows an error...

Answer (score 3):

Interesting idea.  There could be a service to do this, but then the need is probably to small that no one could run a business of it.
You could try posting a request for one of the many freelancing sites.

But like the "feed a man a fish" proverb, you are better off learning how to do this stuff your self then, then you can do it your self.

A lot of the better packers these days leave less of a signature and thus are harder to detect with old/outdated packer detectors.

Go to the forums on:

https://tuts4you.com/

It's pretty much THE site to go to for unpacking info, and if you do your
homework (read up and study first) people will probably help you there.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but in this case the analysis/unpack of this exe file is just a small part of a bigger project and I have a deadline for it so I need someone to do it for me. Later I plan to learn more about unpacking. I am new here and I don´t know if it is allowed to ask but if anyone can help me with this I am willing to pay.